# NLog - Unique Log Files per 'session'?

Tags: vb.net, nlog

Can NLog create unique files everytime a service starts?  For example, I would want to have log files like this:

MyService-01.log
MyService-02.log

for each successive service start, I would want a new log file with the iterative numbering.  I'm coding in vb.net, BTW.  I have nlog working fine and producing a single log file, but I really want to have the functionality described above.

ADDED:

I want to log the location in the service (sub, function, onclick, onstart, etc) where the error has occurred - is that possible?  Still searching this one.

Comment: I got the second part - the location.  Not a big deal there. Still can't figure out multiple logfiles, though.

Comment: Anybody have an idea on this one?